# stomp-websocket + ActiveMQ

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I managed to get ActiveMQ to work with Stomp over WebSockets https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket but I'm having a weird issue related to multiple consumers/subscribers sharing the same IP/router.

Our ActiveMQ server is located outside our office. When two subscribers from the office connect to the queue, the messages dispatched to the queue are being sent only to one subscriber at a time but never to both consumers at the same time.

When I look at the connections tab on the ActiveMQ admin panel I see the following:

ID:ip-10-32-59-175-56297-1352930853863-2:199    StompSocket_565594188   true    false

ID:ip-10-32-59-175-56297-1352930853863-2:370    StompSocket_350506451   true    false

Am I missing something in terms of ActiveMq configuration, is this related to the Stomp JS library or is something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the nature of a Queue, only one subscriber will get a message placed on a Queue, if you want message broadcast then you want to subscribe to a Topic.

[Queue vs Topic](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html)

Comment: Can you share your server side code to listen to messages coming in?